# Line between sections with fullpage-js

Tags: css, fullpage.js

Im trying to create a website with fullpage.js, however im running into an issue where sections with auto-height don't line up right to my next section. (Look at image below)
[image]

Im building this application in Laravel 8 with TailwindCSS.

It looks like the problem has something to do with `fp-auto-height` but i cant figure out what it is.

The code for the section itself is here:

```
<div class="w-full h-full bg-secondary-700 section fp-auto-height">
```

Here you can see the devtools of the element, i have tried removing the padding-top: 1em; but this did **NOT** fix the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue had to do with my body, it was a different background color, and for some reason this made the lines appear, as soon as I changed the background colour to the same colour it all works fine.

Comment: Glad you manage to solve it! And yeah, that's probably the best solution!